# Is there any way to implement this beautiful image effect？

Tags: image, image-processing

Recently I found an amazing APP called Photo Lab,and I'm curious about one effect called Paper Rose.In the pictures below，one is the original picture，the other is the effected picture.My question is what kind of algorithm can do this effect,and it would be better if you can show me some code or demo.Thanks in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Rh5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxfcv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this is not just an algorithm, but a complex piece of software.

The most difficult part is to model the shape of the rose. The petals are probably a meshed surface. It is not so difficult to give them a curved shape, but the hard issue is to group them in such a way that they do not intersect.

It is not quite impossible that this can be achieved by first putting them in a flat geometry where you can master intersections, then to wrap it around an axis with a king of polar transform. But I don't really believe in that. I rather think that they have a collision-avoiding geometric modeller.

The next steps, which are more classical, are to texture-map the pictures onto the petals and to perform the realistic rendering of the whole scene.

---

But there's another option, which I'll call the "poor man's rendering".

You can start from a real picture of a paper rose, where the petals have an empty black, thick frame. Then on the picture, you detect (either in some automated way or just by hand) points that correspond to a regular grid on the flattened paper.

As the petals are not wholly visible, the hidden parts must be clipped out from the mesh, possibly by using a polygonal fence.

Now you can take any picture, fit it over the undistorted mesh, clip out the hidden areas and warp to the distorted position. Then by compositing tricks, you will give it a natural shaded appearance on the rose.

Note: the process is eased by drawing a complet grid inside the frame. Anyway, you will need to somehow erase it before doing the compositing, in order to retrieve just the shading information.

---

I would tend to believe that the second approach was used here, as I see a few mapping anomalies along some edges, which would not arise on a fully synthetic scene.

In any case, hard work.